# How to disable post body (parameters) encoding (spaces turn to +)?

Tags: javascript, post

When I send a form data to a server, the browser encode the parameters value and turn all the white spaces characters into "+" characters like this

`parameter1:"the value of the parameter^@/"`

is turning to

`parameter1:"the+value+of+the+parameter^@/"`

and it also adds the encoding header `Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. But I must disable this encoding, can I do it with JavaScript?

### Edit

I finally realized the server was expecting a JSON parameter not normal form parameter so the parameter looked like this in Firefox developing tools:

[image]

and the normal form looked like this:

[image]

I didn't notice in the parameter tab it is a JSON parameter with white spaces in it's value, so I thought it is a form parameter with white spaces in the values not "+" , and that JSON was submitted to server with jQuery ajax as in this code snippet

```
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: '{ "selected" : "' + selected + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                });
```

And as [Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023618/archer) said in comments that `formenctype attribute` was the way to edit the encoding of the form data.

Also, the server was able to decode the encoded values, it was just keeping reject my requests because it was preparing to receive a JSON not form parameters.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Archer because the server is not prepared to receive encoded parameters and i can't change it

Comment: What server are you using? PHP? Node js? Java?

Comment: Try adding the `formenctype` attribute to one of the inputs... `formenctype="multipart/form-data"` - that should fix the issue.

Comment: @user5407848 asp.net server decode post value automaticaly.

Comment: @Archer thank you that was new attribute to me :)

Comment: @Mohammad yes , you are right , it was just rejecting the request because it was expecting a JSON not a form data with + in it's values , thanks for your help